# Cannot access uielements inside (within) UITableView by using Appium

Tags: uitableview, appium, ui-automation, uiaccessibility

I've being trying to access to the uielements (labels) which are located within UITableViewCell which is located in UITableView. (see the picture below)

[image: The labels within the cell inside the table]

- I set a `setIsAccessibilityElement:YES` and `setAccessibilityLabel`to each required label I can access with no issues.
- I'm adding an accessibility to the cell , still can access to each label in addition to the cell as well
- I'm adding accessibility to the table from this point Appium cannot recognise/inspect the cell and the labels , but only the table ...

[image: Appium inspector]

The thing is , IOS Accessibility inspector (runs from IOS simulator) does able to recognise the table / cell / labels

Any idea what Do I need in the sourcecode of the app in order to make it work with Appium ?

Thanks

Comment: you need to have the accessibilityIdentifiers set up for all the elements.

Comment: All the elements does have an accessibility labels

Comment: not accessibility labels, i mean accessibilityidentifiers.They both are different

Answer (score 1):

Found this on http://appium.io/slate/en/v/?javascript#finding-and-interacting-with-elements

> There’s a known issue with table cell elements becoming invalidated before there’s time to interact with them. We’re working on a fix

However, what I did find was if you were to **.click()** on the UITableView element it picked the row in the center of the screen. Not sure if that's helpful in your testing.